# python удаленное управление windows

Tags: python, windows

Скажите можно ли через python управлять пк(windows) удаленно используя библиотеку socket, смысл такой на пк запущен сервер, клиент подключается и внутри системы выполняет какие-то команды, и так чтобы командная строка не открывалась просто и тихо(все в благих целях!)

Comment: Попробуйте это `import os os.system('"Какая то команда для командной строки"')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такая библиотека для работы с Windows [pywinrm](https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm) попробуйте ее трассировать на ваши требования